# Nessus does not detect sql injection with "Web App Tests"

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, network-scanners

In my website I have an sql injection vulnerability.

But when I scan my website with Nessus under "Web app tests" there is no result on sql injection.

Why is this? What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Ok then. What's your question?

Comment: Welcome to [security.se]. Nessus is a network scanner. You really shouldnt expect a rigorous application scan, even if you might get lucky on occassion. Besides, there is no real question here...

Comment: edited to try and make it a question...

Comment: Try sqlmap http://sqlmap.org/ ; it is the library Metasploit uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nessus is just a tool - it can do things you configure it to, but it is not intelligent in any way.

If you are detecting SQL as an authenticated user, Nessus will not be able to do this unless you allow it to authenticate to your application

If you are detecting it at a specific URL, you need to make sure Nessus is looking at that URL and that it is checking it for SQL.

Many things Nessus misses are down to misconfiguration or permissions, but even once you have set a tool up perfectly, they all have false positives and negatives - which incidentally is why any solely-tool based security scan should **not** be relied on without manual confirmation!